# Private wordpress post redirecting to 404 error - how to make it invisible?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

A post on my website is set to private in the visibility dropdown but the link to the article still appears on the homepage and leads to a 404 error. How can I hide the link from viewers who are not admin?

Comment: you can use wordpress condition [is_admin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin)

Comment: Usually a private post will only show to logged in users (and normally only someone with `edit` access and higher. I would suggest logging out and checking whether the link is still visible?

Comment: I have logged out and the link is still visible, proving frustrating for users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the status of the post from published back to draft, you can still edit it, save it and you can preview it to see the changes and it won't appear on the homepage.

Comment: Thanks, where can I change the status to draft?

Comment: In the top right above visibility, there should be another line saying "Status: Published" with the word edit next to it. If you click edit, a dropdown menu will appear, select draft and then okay and then update.

Comment: There are 'edit' options next to 'visibility' and 'published on' but not next to 'status'. Is there a reason I wouldn't be able to see it?

Comment: If your account role is an admin, there shouldn't be any reason, but if your account role is editor/contributor that might be why you can't see it

Comment: It's definitely admin - can't find anything useful in the wp forums

Comment: can you upload an image of what your publish section shows?

Comment: I have found the dropdown under quick edit, but when I select draft and update it has no effect, the post remains published.

Comment: Is that on the actual website or in the back-end? Because the browser might still have the published post in it's cache. Try viewing the website on a different browser

Comment: It's in the back-end, I have tried viewing in Firefox and the link is still visible and still leads to 404. When I click update status it accepts the change and then automatically changes it back.